# After an ajax need to load a field value and create a select_from_array with the range value

Tags: laravel, advanced-custom-fields, laravel-backpack

Iam trying and not finding a way to load the value from a field and generate a select_from_array based on its range.
For example:
I have 2 select box
Brand -> loads -> Model (using backpack field types, and its working good)

```
`'type'                 => 'select2_from_ajax',
    'name'                 => 'camera_model_id',
    'entity'               => 'camera_model',
    'attribute'            => 'name',
    'data_source'          => url('camera-brands'),
    'placeholder'          => 'Selecione o Modelo',
    'minimum_input_length' => 0,
    'dependencies'         => ['camera_brand_id'],`
```

But, after the user selects this last selectBox, I need that another field was modified

```
`'name'          => 'channel',
'label'         => "Canal da Câmera",
'type'          => 'select2_from_array',
'options'       => ['' => '',
'01' => '01',
'02' => '02', ...`
```

So, the options could be filled with the maximum of the field I registered in the Model field database.
Is it possible? or maybe another approach to achieve the solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To have an input that depends on the value of another input, you can make both your fields [`select2_from_ajax`](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-fields#select2_from_ajax).

That way:

- you will have the value of all inputs in the controller (the controller that returns the ajax results; then you can return a filtered set of results depending on how the form is filled so far - `CategoryController::index()` in the documentation example);
- you can use the "dependencies" attribute on the `selec2_from_ajax` fields, so that when one field is reset, both are;

I hope the answer helps someone. Cheers!